# setup Login System and privilege and permission for Java

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, authentication, module

I'm trying to make a java program that prompt Login for the user and then some options and actions in the program will be available depend on the user permission. so for example , some user can print the picture other can not.

I'm sure this thing have been done many times. I'm looking for a tutorial or code sample to start with. I search in the interent but I couldn't find anything useful. Please help me

Thank you

Comment: You need to tell us a bit more about what you want the user to authenticate against. Do you plan to use a straight connection to a  database on a server, maybe you want to authenticate against an LDAP database, or even a local file?

Comment: I'm not worry about authenticate and Login . I want to know how can I make certain options available for High level users and less options/permission for low level users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and then some options and actions in the program will be available depend on the user permission

Design and build your GUI usings [Actions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). The Actions can be used to create your menu items and toolbar buttons.

Then, after the user is logged in you can disable the Action if the user doesn't have the permission to use that particular function.

Using this approach, the menu items and toolbar buttons will still appear in the UI, however they will be disabled so the user won't be able to use them.

Comment: your help I think it's what I want thank you. I'll read the link about action.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at Acegi  http://www.acegisecurity.org/  , which is a java library that provides features for authorization.

Comment: Thank you , but my problem is not in the login. The thing I want to know is how can I enable some option like printing and make this option not available for low level user.

Comment: Acegi isn't just for authentication (login) it also helps you with access control lists - who has what rights to what features.

Answer (score 1):

Without Acegi Security (if you don't use it). First you must define all components from your application and save it to database. And then, create some tables such as role, user_role and role_components and components. Then when login, you must query this tables and check a security role from table role_components :)

CMIIW